# Arduino-DHT11 library for reading every 30 second

Tags: raspberry-pi3, arduino-ide

does any one here experienced with various dht11 library for arduino?, I want to read the temperature value every 30 second, I am using the standard library  but sometimes throw me NaN. In avarege I got 2 NaN values out of 10 readings (20%).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got many errors about many dht11 libraries, but one day finally I found a good library and good example code.

Firstly you have to download the library from this [link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1eG0a4lXQ2tNuTy_O9OWXuHO-EYbmHRDT) and add this to arduino's library folder.

Secondly, you should do [this](http://www.kodlakafa.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/dht11-s%C4%B1cakl%C4%B1k-nem-sens%C3%B6r%C3%BC-arduino-ba%C4%9Flant%C4%B1s%C4%B1.jpg) pin connections

Lastly, here it is example code. It should work.

```
#include <dht11.h>

int DHT11_pin=2;
dht11 DHT11_sensor;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("GOOD LUCK");
  Serial.println("*********************");
}

void loop()
{
  int chk = DHT11_sensor.read(DHT11_pin);

  Serial.print("Humidity (%): ");
  Serial.println((float)DHT11_sensor.humidity, 2);

  Serial.print("Temp (Celcius): ");
  Serial.println((float)DHT11_sensor.temperature);

  Serial.print("Temp (Kelvin): ");
  Serial.println(DHT11_sensor.kelvin(), 2);

  Serial.print("Temp (Fahrenheit): ");
  Serial.println(DHT11_sensor.fahrenheit(), 2);

  Serial.print("Dew Point: ");
  Serial.println(DHT11_sensor.dewPoint(), 2);

  Serial.println("------------------");
  delay(500);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight, it works. I still curious what will happen if I put 2 or more sensors, right now I only have one DHT sensor, did you have any experiences for multiple DHT in one arduino-uno?.

Comment: why you are using 2 dht? or what is your purpose? I think there are more solutions for your purpose

Comment: Hi @Arda, My purpose is making a spatial heat map of my working room, and I want to put a sensor every 1-meter distance, the room itself has size 16m2 (4x4). therefor I need like an array of DHT to visualize in the map, as the room has a few ventilation, so the temperature and humidity could be varied at some location in the room. any suggestion?